# How hide scrollbar with CSS scroll snap + picture bug in iOS Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, safari

How can I hide a native scrollbar in iOS Safari and Chrome? I am using this code:

```
.scroll-snap-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none!important;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

This does not work in iOS Safari and Chrome.

[image: Arrow showing native scrollbar when scrolling]

Answer (score 0):

Try add this in your code.

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
.scroll-snap-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
display: none!important;
height: 0;
width: 0;
background-color: transparent;
 }
}
```

Comment: without class? just like that? and this should fix what? scrollbar or problem with pictures?

Comment: Its the code to run with chrome and safari. add your class inside of it. I will edit now.

Comment: still not working, that scrollbar is still there :(

Comment: Worked for me but I think this is overcomplicating things. I used just `#gallery::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none !important; }` where #gallery is the div containing my images. Worked in Chrome + iOS